# jquery data value of every object on the page

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm a bit confused.
http://codepen.io/himanshuapril1/full/vNOPrE

If you look at the above referenced code
In the javascript (jquery) how is this working?
Isn't the * setting the data of EVERYTHING to that?

```
var $dd = $('*').data('toggle', 'dropdown');
```

Is this simply selecting everything on the page which has data of toggle-dropdown?

Could someone please shed some light on this for me?
Why if I change the * to a specific class, does this not work?

Comment: You can see that as an reset: select every element and set the value of `data-toggle` to `dropdown` if existing. Alternatively you could change the selector to e.g. `$('i')` but then run into the risk to miss out elements.

Comment: so if I have 2 elements with data-toggle="{I'm assuming this can be anything}. Then this will set their data-toggle BOTH to be data-toggle="dropdown"? Is that correct? thank you by the way!

Comment: @empiric Thank you very much.What I cannot figure out is this: If I change the selector from $('*')  to  $('#notify'). Neither does making the selector $('.container') .... why doesn't that work? My goal is to be able to target a specific item with data-toggle on a page which may have more than one. http://codepen.io/Acts7/pen/jyZxPr

Comment: Because the element you specify must have the `data-toggle` attribute and must be followed by the right elements for the script to work. You narrow your selector with the child selector: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWQegG](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWQegG)

Comment: OH WOW. I see now. I was over-complicating it in my mind. Just like a css selector $('.container *')  ... using .container as a selector then everything within .container. THANK YOU.